# Is there a way to pause execution of a running Java program in Eclipse?

Tags: macos, java, eclipse, pause

I use a MacBook Pro. Sometimes I want to pause the execution of a long heavy-duty experiment running on my system because I am on battery or for any other reason. Is there a way to do it in Eclipse ? Or even in Mac OS X itself ?

Comment: Related question on s.o. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760256/eclipse-break-program ), but presumes that you've started the java program in eclipse in debug mode.  It appears that is the only perspective in which there is a pause (suspend) button.  Otherwise, indeed, signals (sigstop/sigcont sent via `kill`) can be used to pause/resume running processes. If an app is running in the foreground, ctrl+z (typically) sends sigstop signal; `jobs` and  `fg {job_num}` to resume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your process id is `1234`, stop processing with `kill -SIGSTOP 1234`, resume with `kill -SIGCONT 1234`